# Как обернуть определенные по счету символы в контейнере с jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

Есть таблица, в каждом ряду есть ячейка, содержащая 13 символов.

```
<td class="need-to-wrap">0123456789012</td>
```

Мне нужно обернуть символы с 10-го по 12-ый в span вот так:

```
<td class="need-to-wrap">012345678<span>901</span>2</td>
```

Как это сделать с помощью jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var re = /(\d{9})(\d{3})(\d{1})/;
$('td.need-to-wrap').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text(); 
    text = text.replace(re, "$1<span>$2</span>$3");
    $this.html(text);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, самое оно!

Answer (score 1):

Собственно jQuery сам по себе здесь не нужен, можно обойтись и без него. Алгоритм очень прост:

Извлекаем содержимое каждой ячейки в строковую переменную (`innerHTML`  или `html()`, если вам там необходим jQuery). А дальше - стандартными методами строки: [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) или [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) - на выбор. После чего обновляем содержимое ячейки (тем же `innerHTML` / `html()`).

Comment: Спасибо. Я, к сожалению, вообще не программер, я верстак, алгоритм-то задачи понятен, но вот воплотить его в код для меня задача почти нерешаемая.